# How to get the features of Web Essentials in Intellij IDEA

Tags: css, intellij-idea, web-essentials

Hey guys I'm trying to move away from Visual Studio and to Intellij IDEA for web developing however I heavily use the features in the [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) extension. Most of them I can find but I can't seem to find the following features:

- Vendor specific property generation
- Add missing standard properties
- Display browser support for properties and selectors
- Warnings for browser compatibility issues

Does anyone know of a plugin or something that can meet some/all of these features for Intellij IDEA?

Comment: There is **Quirks mode** inspection that you can enable in `Settings` | `Inspections`.

Comment: Okay thanks! That seems to eliminate the bottom two. Any ideas on the top?

Comment: The top two are tracked by http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-4698 and http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6359.

Comment: Okay so the first one looks like they've been aware of it for a while. Second one is fairly recent (this year) so maybe he'll push it out in Idea 13. Sweet. You should post this as an answer so if no one else comes up with something I can mark yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **Quirks mode** inspection that you can enable in `Settings` | `Inspections`, it will cover the bottom 2 features.

Unfortunately, the first 2 features are not implemented yet:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-4698
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6359